# Apple certificate Nginx causes 301 redirect if there's no trailing slash

Tags: nginx

I have a file `apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association` which should be served on path `/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`

So I added a location to my nginx config

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name website.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;

    location /.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association {
        alias /etc/nginx/apple;
        index apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association;
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        allow all;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass ...;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

The problem is `https://website.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association` redirects to `https://website.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association/` and the service I am using check the url without the trailing slash

I tried with `absolute_redirect off;` on server and location but I have the same result